# upload file in the web view is not working

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

to be honest i just wanted to create a an application to view a website i'm not android developer.inside this website there is an option for uploading file image file and it doesn't work could any one please tell me whats going on this is my java class

```
package com.example.median1.psalmsmarket;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class Psalms extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdView mAdview;

    WebView webview;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_psalms);


        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8815429757385123~7800940961");



webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.Pslams);
        WebSettings webSettings=webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.org/");



        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webview, true);
        }else {
            CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
        }




    }




}
```

and these are the permissions that i should give to my project

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You want an app to view a site, ok. But this site works as a site? (I.e.: it does the upload in a traditional browser, in a Unix-Win-Mac platform?)

Comment: okay the thing is i need to give a file  permission to application that view the website so it will allow the website to upload file but i don't know how

Comment: I am really sorry if I did not understand you well, but configuring a webview you can setup a personal **user agent** for that webview. Then, backside, you can use a PHP function, for example, to react according to the user agent you detect. If a "normal" user agent is visiting your site, ok, show him plain content. If your personalized and special **user agent** is detected then you allow it "special functions" to use.